# Convert a simple Array to complex Object with items as child array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using javascript ES6, I'm trying without success to get an easy algorithm to convert an array who contains a string, **no size limit** and I need as a result an object with array items as label and every item in a child array, depending on his position, kind of hard to explain,

Here is what I got "before" and what I want "after".

```
before = ["a","b","c","d"]

after = {
        name: "a"
        children: [
            {
                name: "b",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "c",
                        children: [
                            name: "d"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I'm totally blocked thanks for any help

Comment: Are you open to using recursion?

Comment: Yes i don't know so much about that actually ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to create the structure from the array.

The `reduceRight()` takes an element from the end, wraps it with the object, and add the previous result into the children array. The children are assign conditionally using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), since the last object doesn't have children.

```js
const before = ["a","b","c","d"];

const after = before.reduceRight((r, name) => 
  Object.assign({ name }, r !== null ? { children: [r] } : {}), 
  null);

console.log(after);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, without using those fancy `const` and `reduceRight` stuff!  =D

```js
var before = ["a","b","c","d"];

var after = createChildren(before);

console.log(after);

function createChildren(obj) {
    if (obj.length) {
      return { name: obj.shift(), children: [ createChildren(obj)] };
    }
    return new Array();
}
```

Shorter version:

```js
var before = ["a","b","c","d"];

var after = createChildren(before);

console.log(after);

function createChildren(obj) {
    return obj.length && { name: obj.shift(), children: [ createChildren(obj)] } ||
           new Array();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```js
const after = ([name, ...rest], children = rest.length && [after(rest)]) => 
  children 
    ? { name, children } 
    : { name };

const before = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(after(before), null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to the one by Ori Dori, but it doesn't use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
["a","b","c","d"].reduceRight((r, v, i) => {
    r.name = v;
    return i === 0 ? r : { children: [r] }
}, {});
```